# link 2 computer over the internet

Tags: 14.04, networking, software-recommendation, lubuntu, kubuntu

I have 2 desktop computers and I would like to connect both of these computers together over the internet so I could access the information from one room to another. the computer with the files I would like to get from had kubuntu and the other I would like to the files through is a lubuntu both are 14.04 I tried samba but I’m having much to much problems and I don’t mind sharing the hard drive either but please be very descriptive

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to install the OpenSSH server on your Kubuntu machine. You just need the indicate the `ssh` package, available from the Software Centre; alternatively you may use the command line:

`sudo apt-get install ssh`

Then you can access it from the Lubuntu machine with your file browser of choice (with Nautilus or Nemo this would be *File* -> *Connect to Server...*). You need to provide the IP address of the Kubuntu system and indicate 22 as the port.

For the command line you have tools such as [ssh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ssh.1.html) (the client) and [scp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/scp.1.html).

Comment: OK when i did it asked me for a password so i entered my username login from the kubuntu computer and it said incorrect password  then not mounted

Comment: No, they do not need to be in the same network, although in your case I believe they are. If you already have an application using port 22 then you should configure the ssh server to use a different port. Follow [the instructions in the Wiki](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.ubuntu.com%2Fcommunity%2FSSH%2FOpenSSH%2FConfiguring). P.S.: using port 22 for something other than SSH is not a good idea.

Comment: That means you entered an incorrect password.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `openssh-server` and not just `ssh`?

Comment: how do i find the password or is it the usernames login for the kubuntu computer

Comment: know i see i had to enter the login as as the computers username and not mine and then the password as that computers password

Comment: Good. If the issue is solved then consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can **share folder** between computer  or use **SSH** [help for ssh](http://rcc.its.psu.edu/user_guides/remote_connectivity/ssh/) if you are in same network .

if you are not in same network than you have to use **Team Viewer**. for access another PC.

Comment: team viewer only allows certain files and im gonna try openssh now